# Stop the running Function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Actually i am trying to scroll function. Based on currentY position it will call either autoScroll() or resetScroll().
But the problem is while autoScroll() is still running if we again hit to call resetScroll() both are collapsing and my page is not working(its moving up and down fastly).SO HOW TO STOP THE PREVIOUSLY RUNNING FUNCTION.

#### HTML:

```
<h2 id="myheading">JavaScript Smooth Animated Auto Scroll Tutorial</h2>
<a href="#" onclick="return false;" onmousedown="scrollTo('div1');">
 Document Section 1</a><br />
<a href="#" onclick="return false;" onmousedown="scrollTo('div2');">
Document Section 2</a><br />
<a href="#" onclick="return false;" onmousedown="scrollTo('div3');">
Document Section 3</a><br />
<a href="#" onclick="return false;" onmousedown="scrollTo('div4');">
Document Section 4</a><br />
<div id="div1" class="contentbox">Div 1 content...</div>

<div id="div2" class="contentbox">Div 2 content...</div>

<div id="div3" class="contentbox">Div 3 content...</div>

<div id="div4" class="contentbox">Div 4 content...</div>
```

#### CSS:

```
div.contentbox {
background: #FFF;
height: 500px;
margin: 20px;
font-size: 28px;
border: #CCC 1px dashed;
}
a{position: fixed;}
```

#### JS:

```js
var distance = 40;
var scrollY = 0;

function scrollTo(mk) {

  var currentY = window.pageYOffset;
  var targetY = document.getElementById(mk).offsetTop;
  if (currentY < targetY) {
    autoScrollTo(mk);
  } else {
    resetScroller(mk)
  }
}

function autoScrollTo(el) {
  var currentY = window.pageYOffset;
  var targetY = document.getElementById(el).offsetTop
  var bodyHeight = document.body.offsetHeight;
  var yPos = currentY + window.innerHeight;
  var animate = setTimeout('autoScrollTo(\'' + el + '\')', 24);
  if (yPos > bodyHeight) {
    clearTimeout(animate);
  } else {
    if (currentY < targetY - distance) {
      scrollY = currentY + distance;
      window.scroll(0, scrollY);
    } else {
      clearTimeout(animate);
    }
  }
  console.log(scrollY);
}


function resetScroller(rs) {
  var scrollYR = 0;
  var currentYR = window.pageYOffset;
  var targetYR = document.getElementById(rs).offsetTop;
  var animateR = setTimeout('resetScroller(\'' + rs + '\')', 24);

  if (currentYR > targetYR) {
    scrollYR = currentYR - distance;
    window.scroll(0, scrollYR);
  } else {
    clearTimeout(animateR);
  }
  console.log(scrollYR);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check for exit strategy in your autoScroll function, based on some global variable - which you can set from your other functions...

Comment: Can explain more about that(an example).

Answer (score 0):

You need to remember which scroll event is in progress for which you can keep a flag globally and once you get a new request you need to ensure that previous element knows about it to.

Change the scrollTo method to

```
var currentScroll = "";
function scrollTo(mk) {
  var currentY = window.pageYOffset;
  var targetY = document.getElementById(mk).offsetTop;
  if (mk != currentScoll )
  {
     document.getElementById(currentScoll).setAttribute("data-animation", "STOP");
     currentScoll = mk;
  }
  if (currentY < targetY) {
    autoScrollTo(mk);
  } else {
    resetScroller(mk)
  }
}
```

and your `autoScrollTo` method

```
function autoScrollTo(el) {
  var currentY = window.pageYOffset;
  var targetY = document.getElementById(el).offsetTop
  var bodyHeight = document.body.offsetHeight;
  var yPos = currentY + window.innerHeight;
  if ( document.getElementById(el).getAttribute("data-animation") == "STOP")
  {
    document.getElementById(el).removeAttribute("data-animation");
    currentScoll = "";
    return false;
  }
  var animate = setTimeout('autoScrollTo(\'' + el + '\')', 24);
  if (yPos > bodyHeight) {
    clearTimeout(animate);
  } else {
    if (currentY < targetY - distance) {
      scrollY = currentY + distance;
      window.scroll(0, scrollY);
    } else {
      clearTimeout(animate);
    }
  }
  console.log(scrollY);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but, Instead of alert i want to stop previous function and i want to start the new function. How to do that??

Comment: @manikantakoppala so you want to stop current animation instead of blocking new one?

Comment: Yes @gurvinder. Can you help me out?

Comment: @Manikantakoppala I have updated the code, can you check and revert?